# Jquery append() isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<ul>`

```
<ul id="select_opts" class="bullet-list" style="margin-left:15px;"></ul>
```

This javascript code which is meant to go throug a JSON object and add the options 
to the UL:

```
$.each(q.opts, function(i,o)
{                        
    var str='';
    str+="<li id='li_" + i + "'><input type='text' id='opt_" + i + "' value='" + o.option + "'>";
    str+=" (<a href='javascript:delOpt(" + i + ");'>Delete</a>) </li>";
    $("#select_opts").append(str);

});
```

If I do console.log() I can see that the looping is working. If I do:

```
console.log($("#select_opts").html());
```

It shows the HTML being updated as expected. However in the browser window, it shows the 
UL as empty!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, another part of the code was emptying the `<ul>` when i clicked a certain button.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("select_opts").append(str);
```

should be

```
$("#select_opts").append(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

you're referring to object by id so you missed #

```
$.each(q.opts, function(i,o)
{                        
    var str='';
    str+="<li id='li_" + i + "'><input type='text' id='opt_" + i + "' value='" + o.option + "'>";
    str+=" (<a href='javascript:delOpt(" + i + ");'>Delete</a>) </li>";
    $("#select_opts").append(str);
   //  ^
}
```

Comment: if it doesn't try checking if the loop is actually executed?
try putting alert('this works'); inside.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a typo?:

```
$("select_opts").append(str);
```

Did you mean?:

```
$("#select_opts").append(str);
```

**UPDATED:**

Try this:

```
$.each(q.opts, function(i, o) {
    var li = $('<li>').attr('id', 'li_' + i);
    var in = $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('id', 'opt_' + i).val(o.option);
    var aa = $('<a>').attr('href', 'javascript:delOpt(' + i + ');').text('Delete');
    li.append(in).append(aa)
    $("#select_opts").append(li);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see what's wrong, but try this instead, just to see if it works...

```
$(str).appendTo("#select_opts");
```

Both should work.

Answer (score 1):

The tag Input should be closed - if don't, when using not valid html in append() on Internet Explorer, the div is not put into DOM tree, so you cannot access it with jQuery later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine `input` needs to be properly self-closed.

Comment: only if it's xhtml, but even then, this shouldn't affect the javascript.